# Unity Editor takes long time to start

Tags: unity

Starting unity editor (2020.3.20f) takes a minimum of 10-15 minutes even on fresh projects, Same thing happens with the Old (2019) and New(2021) versions. Even faced this issue in 2020.3.19f. I hardly even see any activity in task manager confirming that its not that intensive too.

Searching online about it I tried disabling my Antivirus, I don't use VPN and Starting unity editor with flags, and several options saw on unity forums but nothing seems to work.

I only see this screen for all that time
[image: Reference Image]

Comment: Have you tried to remove it completely and start again with a fresh install? Including additional packages, such as VS or VSC installs. As currently stated, your question doesn't provide enough information for us to find a possible working solution.

Comment: How powerful is your computer?

Comment: @liggiorgio Do you mean Entire Unity Hub and all?

Comment: @Philipp It's a Rog Laptop Ryzen 7 and rtx 3050

Comment: @liggiorgio What information can be useful I'm new to unity so I'm not sure. I tried Reinstalling everything several times did not work

Comment: One thing to check... Unity uses local networking sockets to communicate between various components. "Starting server" might imply it was timing out waiting for a port to be available/for a firewall approval. Do you have any software that blocks apps running as a server?

Comment: I had antivirus though I completely uninstalled it, and unity also asked for firewall permission last time I opened it which I gave. How can I confirm this is an issue?